# phonegap how to store files in the local filesystem

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm looking for the appropriate way of storing files into the document folder within phonegap/cordova.

I've done some google searches but all I seem to find is how to use local storage or webSQL.

Also looked at the phonegap plugins github page but nothing seems promising.

The file I'm looking to store is actually a binary file I'll download from the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you will want to use [FileTransfer.download](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer_download) to get the binary file from the internet. Then you can manipulate it using the [File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File).

Comment: Thanks Simon, I'll try it out and let you know the results.

Comment: Here's a more detailed explanation of the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417055/download-files-and-store-them-locally-with-phonegap-jquery-mobile-android-and-io