# (Phonegap + iOS) Why when I get the full path of the filesystem in a device or simulator I get only "/"?

Tags: ios, cordova

Im running this simple code when the device ready is fired:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs){

var imagesRootPath = fs.root.fullPath;
navigator.notification.alert(imagesRootPath);


},
function(evt) { navigator.notification.alert(evt.target.error.code)});
```

In a MAC pro with Phonegap 3.2 this works perfectly, when it code is running in the simulator, the imagesRootPath is a long string path. When I run this code deployed in a Ipod device, I get other different long path.

Now, when I run this code in a NOTEBOOK that has the same MacOS than the Mac Pro, but has Phonegap 3.3, I get in the simulator only "/" (slash) path and the same slash in when I deploy the Phonegap app on the device.

I made the proper plugin configuration for file API.

What may be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I think your question is not logically and clearly stated, and very hard to understand the situation. I recommend  you to edit your contents with list style. For instance "perfect" or "long" does mean nothing to the people who try to answer. Why don't you make the result stated specific.

Comment: What don't you understand? I explain the difference between two scenaries and a clear problem, I only receive by fullPath  a slash

Comment: when-different-now-when-but- This is a real bad example to explain things. two scenarios in only your head. You have several factors mixed in the same statement. Phonegap 3.2 and 3.3, MacOS, MacPro, NOTEBOOK, simulator, device. What are you talking about??

Comment: Well, I think what @KenOKABE is talking about is that you should eliminate some variables to get a better understanding of what is going on here: can't you install the same Phonegap Version on both of your systems? Can't you install the App from both the MacPro and the notebook to your device and can tell the difference?

Comment: Thanks Nils!, I will try to update the version of MAC PRO, and I edit  my question to clarify the problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The latest release of Cordova changed the way the File plugin works with paths significantly. What you're seeing is actually the expected behaviour of the File plugin if you use the earlier documentation. (I was having the exact same problem with my older code).

http://cordova.apache.org/news/2014/02/10/plugins-release.html
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/dev/doc/index.md - check out the upgrade notes.

Comment: Wow I didn't expect this unprofessional handling by Cordova. If I didn't find this answer here, I would be still banging my head on the wall

Comment: This was the solution!! You are great Chris! :)

Comment: I still can't make it work! Can you add an example ? A simple file copy from a cdvfile:// or file:/// to another dir. I have a simple fileEntry.copyTo(dirEntry); that stopped working with new File plugin

Answer (score 10):

In current plugin dev branch there is a solution:

**Entry.toNativeURL()** - Returns the full path to the file in the device FileSystem.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/tree/dev

Answer (score 2):

It's a shame this question was down voted because of its confusing explanation. I am having the same problem: `fileEntry.fullPath` returns **'/fileName'** instead of the actual file path. I see this behavior in versions 3.1 and 3.2 of phonegap as well.

Just so it's clear, by actual file path I mean something like: **/Users/user/Library/Application Support/.../.../.../fileName'**

Comment: I installed the same Phonegap version in both MacbookPro and Notebook (3.3) and I tried run the same code. In the notebook I got the path: "/" and at the MacBookPro the real file path. I guess that there's a error with Phonegap running in a notebook wish MacOs.

Answer (score 2):

According to the doc:

> If your application works with device-absolute-paths, and you previously retrieved those paths through the `fullPath` property of `Entry` objects, then you should update your code to use `entry.toURL()` instead.