# Cordova / Phonegap and iOS 8.1 path to Library

Tags: html, ios, cordova, ios8

I use cordova to compile an HTML / JS project to an app.

What Im doing is to use assets located inside the public folder inside the app itself, like :

```
../../../../Library/Caches/data/media/image.png
```

It worked fine until iOS 8.1 . The media files are in the folder, but for some reason they can not be loaded inside /www .

Is there anything that has changed with this path in iOS 8.1 ?

I use Cordova 3.1.0 . Do I need to update ?

What changes do i have to make in order to make this work ? Thanks !

Comment: For iOS8 you need to be on `cordova 3.6.x`

Comment: Yep, I've done this. How can I access to the Cache folder after I've updated Cordova to 3.6 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I resolved my problem.
Here what i had as asset paths :

```
../../../../Library/Caches/[path to file]
```

And now, what works with Cordova 3.6 + File plugin ( don't know if its mandatory ) is :

```
cdvfile://localhost/cache/[path to file]
```

Links : 
http://cordova.apache.org/news/2014/02/10/plugins-release.html

[(Phonegap + iOS) Why when I get the full path of the filesystem in a device or simulator I get only "/"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756274/phonegap-ios-why-when-i-get-the-full-path-of-the-filesystem-in-a-device-or-s)

http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.file