# iOS App - How to Save Audios into iCloud

Tags: ios, cordova, download, icloud

I have a PhoneGap App for iOS that plays Audios from a server. Users are asking me to provide download option and I am not sure how can I do that on iOS.

Can someone please if it is possible throw the MP3 file to user's iCloud directly?

Or any other methods to save audio files for offline listening?

Regards

Comment: I wouldn't store to iCloud, especially if they want offline access because then you couldn't get it. You could probably do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9940951/2281093) to download the file and store it locally.

Comment: It's possible to save any file to iCloud. Whether it's possible with PhoneGap is a different question, though. If they offer iCloud integration, it would be the same as saving any other file in iCloud.