# phonegap image download and store locally

Tags: android, jquery, phonegap-plugins

I am new to phonegap app development. I am writing a shopping cart that needs to work offline. I created the project using the Phonegap desktop application. I am just about finished it but one thing I cannot get working is I need to download product images and store them locally.
I have tried a few different functions posted already like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417055/download-files-and-store-them-locally-with-phonegap-jquery-mobile-android-and-io)

NOthing works. It just hangs for a second then nothing happens. I have the following in the config.xml:

```
 <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file"/>
 <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer"/>
```

I think I read that plugins don't work until you build it but I tried building it using Phonegap Build, which is fine but it didn't make any difference with regards the image files downloading.

I can successfully download JSON strings from my web service written in C# using .ajax and parse them but can't see how to download some jpegs and store them.

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm thinking it must be something simple but I can't figure it out. 
thanks

Comment: I notice from the link I included above there is another plugin that simplifies it but I have no idea how to add the plugin (what format) through the config.xml file. [simplefilemanagement](https://github.com/torrmal/cordova-simplefilemanagement)