# Phonegap access the "www" folder

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, file-transfer

I'm building an app which should download a file from a server and save it "in the app". I'm using FileTransfer for this.
Now I want to ask if it's possible to save the file in my "www" folder? If not, where should I save this file?

I tried it with fileSystem.root.fullPath, but where is the "www" folder in ios?

thank you!

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9940951/1156668

Comment: yes, but i want safe it in my "www" folder

Answer (score 0):

The application directory contains the www folder of your app. **However**, that location is read only, so you won't be able to store your data in there. For storage, the file system root is a good choice. On ios, it correspond to the Documents directory, which is persistent read/write storage, i think it suits most app's needs. I'll still show how to access the application folder in case you're interested on accessing some files there.

---

When using the file plugin, you can access iOS's application inner folders using the `cordova.file.applicationDirectory` location (for other iOS locations, check out the table at https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#ios-file-system-layout). Use it with `resolveLocalFileSystemURI`, and it'll give a directory entry at said location to its success callback.

From there you can then access the www folder by using `getDirectory`.

**Short Example**

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(cordova.file.applicationDirectory,
    function(appDirectory) {
         appDirectory.getDirectory("www", {create:false}, onSuccess, onFailure);
    }, 
onFailure);
```