# How to download any file in PhoneGap using C# Webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, phonegap-build

I have no idea of how to download a file using a C# web service.

Please help me with the following C# code.

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("http://some.server.com/File.docx");

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    downloadPath,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("Download compelete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("Download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("Download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("Upload error code" + error.code);
    },
    false
);
```

But I don't want to give a URL like this. I want to download through Webservice. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague. I would suggest adding more details to try and get more answers. I can make the following recommendations for you to look into:

1. [Cordova File Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) - This plugin allows your cordova app to mess with the files on the mobile's devices disk. I.e this lets you read and write files locally.
2. [Cordova File Transfer Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) - This plugin allows you to connect to remote services (for example your C# service) and download files from them.
3. [Cordova White List Plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/appdev/whitelist/) - This is **essential** if you want to connect to external websites and services. Without this plugin and without defining your whitelist in `config.xml` you will not be able to connect to anything remotely.

I would also recommend looking at [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/victorsh/entry/march_11_2014_8_58_pm?lang=en) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417055/download-files-and-store-them-locally-with-phonegap-jquery-mobile-android-and-io) for more info.